# unknown output in snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm working on implementing a very simple pipeline in snakemake in hopes of replacing a chain of annoying bash scripts with one cohesive Snakefile.

I'm having trouble writing a rule that splits a file into smaller pieces (using GNU split), and then leads to a second rule where the output is concatenated together.

I don't know what to write for the input in the concat step, since I don't know how to define all the files fitting the pattern `bam_files/test*`. I tried with glob, but that decidedly doesn't seem to work (it seems like it's actually skipping split altogether with the glob included). Is there any better way that I could be doing this?

```
# test snakemake pipeline
import glob


SAMPLE_IDS = ["test"]

rule all: 
    input: 
        expand("bam_files/{FASTQ}.out", FASTQ=SAMPLE_IDS)


rule split: 
    input: 
        expand("{FASTQ}.txt", FASTQ=SAMPLE_IDS)
    output: 
        "bam_files/{FASTQ}."
    shell:
        "cat {input} | split -l 1000 -d - {output}."


rule concat: 
    input:
        split_files = glob.glob("bam_files/{FASTQ}.*")
    output: 
        "bam_files/{FASTQ}.out"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: Have you looked into `dynamic()`? [Source](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SAMPLE_IDS = ["test"]

rule all: 
    input: 
        expand("bam_files/{FASTQ}.out", FASTQ=SAMPLE_IDS)


rule split: 
    input: 
        "{FASTQ}.txt"
    output: 
        dynamic("bam_files/{FASTQ}.{PART}")
    params:
        length=1000
    shell:
        "cat {input} | split -l {params.length} -d - bam_files/{FASTQ}."


rule concat: 
    input:
        split_files = dynamic("bam_files/{FASTQ}.{PART}")
    output: 
        "bam_files/{FASTQ}.out"
    shell: 
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

It looks like the `split` rule should be taking one file `{FASTQ}.txt` at a time and producing `{FASTQ}.1, {FASTQ}.2, ...` or something similar. Because you don't know ahead of time how many files it will produce, you need to use `dynamic()` for both `split.output` and `concat.input`.