# How do I define a Snakemake workflow with an unknown number of output files?

Tags: dynamic, snakemake

I have a workflow where it's possible that there is no output for some of my samples. Snakemake eats my Snakefile with `dynamic("{sample}...")` inputs and outputs. However, it also tries to produce a file literally called "{sample}.out", which no rule ever produces since the wildcards are substituted.

This is my example Snakefile to demonstrate the workflow. There is only one rule with unknown number of output files, the following one(s) should work on the files that were produced by the first.

```
rule all:
        input: dynamic(expand("{sample}.out", sample = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]))

rule first:
        output:
                dynamic("{sample}.intermediate")
        shell:
                "(( $RANDOM % 2 )) && touch {output} || true"

rule second:
        input:
                dynamic("{sample}.intermediate")
        output:
                "{sample}.out"
        shell:
                "echo 'processed' > {output}"
```

After one round of Snakemake, not all output files are present because of the random factor in the first rule (it's *possible* that all are produced; just delete them and rerun the example). Snakemake fails with a MissingOutputException:

```
MissingOutputException in line 4 of Snakefile:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds:
{sample}.intermediate
```

In my real data, there is no randomness involved, but I cannot predict the final number of output files. I have a list of possible sample names that I expand to the list of the target files, but no way to know which (if any) will result in output.

I have seen the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598637/unknown-output-in-snakemake) and it helped understand that for every `dynamic()` output there must be another rule that takes `dynamic()` input. I don't understand why Snakemake tries to produce the files "{sample}.out". How can I fix this and get a non-predictable set of output files?

Comment: Take a look at checkpoints: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution

Comment: did you try to just give a directory for output? If your next rule just picks up all the generated output from there then I think it should be fine.